# Board not making piece move

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to make a button move to another place, i used this code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<=29; i++)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == gB[i])
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is draw board

```
public void drawBoard()
{
    JPanel gboard = new JPanel();

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        gboard.add(gB[i]);
        gB[i].setText(Integer.toString(gB[i].getPieceValue()));

    }
```

which I think is wrong. Anyone have any idea? I'm not able to get the players moving to the next position.

Thanks

the error is: (**all in RED**)

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Controller.actionPerformed(Controller.java:22)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
```

Comment: what is gB, I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Your method `actionPerformed` doesn't do anything apart from write to System.out. Is that intentional?

Comment: For better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: Yeah, where do you THINK it should be moving the game piece?  Because I don't see that in the code you provide.

Comment: basically when i compile and run, this errors cums.Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Controller.actionPerformed(Controller.java:22) which is:             if(e.getSource() == gB[i])
also gB is     private Piece[] gB;
thanks

Comment: @farhad a wrote `which I think is wrong. Anyone have any idea?` no one have got idea from that code snipped, nor to see the code in your monitor, for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: the problem is that, i get the error when i compile, look at last comment

Comment: does gB[] always contain 30 initialised Pieces?

Comment: @DeneB layout of the board:

this.add(gboard);
        gboard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,10));
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        setResizable(false);

Comment: @farhad: put any and all error messages into your original question. Simply press the "edit" link on the bottom of your original post, and then add it there. It's very difficult to read error messages and code in comments. But looking at your code, it's completely off the mark. You're creating a JPanel inside of a method for no reason, and then it is discarded. You've got to work with components that are already displayed, not create new JPanels. Go through the Swing tutorials a bit to see how things are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<=29; i++)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == gB[i])
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

has only a few names which could hold a value.  The `ActionEvent` named "e" and the array named "gB" are the only names which could be set to null.

That means either you threw a custom ActionEvent without defining a source, or you didn't initalize the array gB.

If you wanted your piece to move, it would probably also help to do more than printout the value of "i" in the action handler; but, I'm guessing you haven't made it that far in your effort yet.

Comment: hmm, the thing is i got code but i cant implement it to the existing code i have because i start getting errors, hmm